# Comparing two object of type circle

Tags: java, compare, comparator, comparable

**Create a Java class named “Circle” that implements java.io.Serializable interface  and models a circle based on radius. Radius cannot be less than zero. Implement the getter and setter method for radius. Also include an overriding of toString in the circle class. Create the class' comparator which compares two objects of type Circle.**

This is what I have so far

```
import java.io.Serializable;


public class Circle implements Serializable, Comparable<Circle> {

private int radius = 1;

public Circle() {
}


public Circle(int radius) {
    setRadius(radius);

}

public void setRadius(int v) {
    if (v > 0) {
        this.radius = v;
    }

}

public int getRadius() {
    return this.radius;

}



@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Circle{" + "radius=" + radius + '}';
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Circle o) {
    //no idea what to put here

}



}
```

This my comparator class

```
 import java.util.Comparator;

public class CompareCircle implements Comparator<Circle> {

CompareCircle(Circle c1, Circle c2) {

}

@Override
public int compare(Circle o1, Circle o2) {
    if (o1.getRadius() > o2.getRadius()) {
        return o1.getRadius();
    } else {
        return o2.getRadius();
    }

}
}
```

My question is did I do this right or no?

Comment: No, you didn't. Read the javadoc of Comparator to understand why it's for, and what its compare() method should return. Don't implement Comparable is you use a Comparator to compare circles.

Comment: //no idea what to put here - you can write
'return Integer.comapre(this.getRadius(), o.getRadius())'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As JB pointed out `Circle` class does not need to implement `Comparable` if you use comperator:

```
public class Circle implements Serializable /*, Comparable<Circle> */{
```

In `CompareCircle` you can drop the constructor (actually use the default constructor `CompareCircle()` ).

The `compare` method should also handle the case of two equal circles:

```
@Override
public int compare(Circle o1, Circle o2) {
    //you may want to consider cases where one circle or both are null 
    if (o1.getRadius() > o2.getRadius()) {
        return o1.getRadius();
    } else if (o1.getRadius() == o2.getRadius()) {
        return 0;
    }           
       return o2.getRadius();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to implement `Comparable` or override `compareTo()`.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-), this is what `compare()` should return:

> Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

You can use [Integer.compare()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-) to satisfy these requirements:

> Returns:
>   the value 0 if x == y; a value less than 0 if x < y; and a value greater than 0 if x > y

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class CompareCircle implements Comparator<Circle> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Circle o1, Circle o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o1.getRadius(), o2.getRadius());
    }
}
```

To compare, you need to create an instance of `CompareCircle`. You can use it with [Collections.max()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-java.util.Comparator-) to retrieve the largest object:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<Circle> list = new ArrayList<Circle>() {{
            add(new Circle(4));
            add(new Circle(7));
            add(new Circle(2));
        }};

        CompareCircle comp = new CompareCircle();
        Circle c = Collections.max(list, comp);

        System.out.println(c.getRadius());
    }
}
```

Ouput:

> 7

Comment: Please don't advertise using subtraction to implement the comparison of two integers. Use Integer.compare(). Subtraction will fail due to integer overflow with very large values.

Comment: What if I want to return largest out of 2 or 3 circles?

Comment: @JohnCasey Use `Collections.max()` - I've updated my answer. @JBNizet In this case, I assume a radius will never be negative because it doesn't geometrically make sense. Therefore, overflow wont occur. However, it is good practise and I have updated the code.